# Run a script automatically when I'm connected to the internet on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, automation, shell-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run script in OS X 10.6 on network connection. (like /etc/network/if-up.d/)](https://superuser.com/questions/201478/run-script-in-os-x-10-6-on-network-connection-like-etc-network-if-up-d)

I set up ssh tunnels so that I can access various computers at work through our gateway.  The problem is, I don't like having to always set these up each time I turn on my computer or connect/disconnect to the internet so I'm hoping that there is a way that I can automatically run a shell script to set up the tunnels whenever I connect to the internet.  I have something similar setup on my workstation in the office which is running Ubuntu and it uses the /etc/network/if-up.d and if-down.d.  Is there an equivalent on the Mac?

Comment: Possible [Duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/201478/run-script-in-os-x-10-6-on-network-connection-like-etc-network-if-up-d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess context-aware tools such as [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) can do the trick, surely if you use some shell script to set up the tunnels:

> Flexible rule-based fuzzy matching on:
>
> - [..]
> - Assigned IP addresses
> - Active Network Links
> - Visible WiFi networks
>
> Actions triggered by changing context (either entering or leaving), with an optional delay:
>
> - [..]
> - Mounting network shares (smb://, afp://, etc.)
> - Changing OS X network location
> - Quit an application
> - Running a shell script (or any other kind of script, via [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus))
> - Establish or disconnect VPN

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing MarcoPolo can handle and I've used it in the past to establish a VPN tunnel when ever I connect to a specific network (when moving a computer from work to home and back again). Very handy tool.

Comment: This is looking quite promising - I'll have to play around with it for a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Not built-in; this sort of thing is generally handled by launchd on OS X, but network up/down events are not on its list of triggers.  Fortunately, [PyMacAdmin](http://code.google.com/p/pymacadmin/) includes a program, crankd, which provides this capability.  [Here](http://glarizza.posterous.com/using-crankd-to-react-to-network-events) is an example of using crankd to do something similar (although he's using it to launch a Python module rather than a shell script, so the details are a bit different).  I haven't tried this, but it looks like you'd just need to create a crankd plist file something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>SystemConfiguration</key>
    <dict>
        <key>State:/Network/Global/IPv4</key>
        <dict>
            <key>command</key>
            <string>/usr/local/libexec/networkchangescript</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

... then write /usr/local/libexec/networkchangescript to detect whether the network is up (AIUI it'll get launched for any change, whether up, down, or sideways) and set up tunnels if appropriate.  Finally, create a launchd plist to run crankd (see the example I linked for details).